# jqGrid add button for addrow

Tags: jqgrid

Can I create a button outside of the grid like placing a input button on the form and have it call a method like below to add a row to the grid?

```
function NewRow($) {
var myrow = {ID:5, ProjectName: "NewProject");
$("#grid").jqGrid('addRow', myrow);
}

<input type="button" value="PFM" onclick="NewRow()"/>
```

I tried as above and keep getting object expected error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why ist there a '$' (function NewRow($)) in the function definition?

You can add a new row with:

```
parameters =
{
    rowID : "new_row",
    initdata : {
        ProjectName: "NewProject"
    },
    position :"last",
}
$("#myGridID").jqGrid('addRow', parameters);
```

[jqGrid Wiki example](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing)